# Uploaded List templates are not available in add an app in SharePoint 2013

Tags: list-template

I have got a list template(.stp) which I have imported in my site by going to "Web Designer Galleries -> List templates" in Site Settings.

After that I went to Site Contents to create a new list based on this template but I don't see any option to create.

**FYI:**
    1. Activated "Team Collaboration Lists Feature" and it not works.
    2. List templates are not available even after search.
    3. Is there any issue if the list template is from a list which was migrated            from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013?

Thanks in advance.............

Comment: We are having this issue with a dynamically-generated custom list created by a Visual Studio workflow in SP 2010, when migrating that list to SP 2016 as a list template.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it seems to be that my List template was not shown because it had the wrong language id. I followed the following steps to resolve this issue:

- The first thing what you have to do is to save the template on your
  local computer.
- Then rename the template.stp into template.cab
- Extract all files of the *.cab file
- In the extracted folder you will find an manifest.xml. Open it with an editor e.g. notepad++ or textpad and replace the current language id with the your one (1043 for Dutch) search the manifest file for the following strings

  - `<Language>1033</Language>`
  - `<Locale>1033</Locale>`
  - `1033\STS\`
  - `Layouts\1033\`
  - `/_layouts/1033/`
- Save the manifest file with your changes
- The next step is to create a new .cab file with the changes you made. To do
  this use `makecab.exe` (in Windows under `%WINDIR%\system32`) - ex:

  `makecab manifest.xml ListTemplate.cab`

  will turn it into a .cab again.
- Rename the generated *.cab file into *.stp
- Upload the new template into you new enviroment
- And create the List with the new template

The following helped me a lot: [MOSS How To: Change List/Site Template language](https://developers.de/blogs/nadine_storandt/archive/2009/03/18/moss-how-to-change-list-site-template-language.aspx)

Comment: This can be useful for someone even if it's not a language ID issue, but just to compare a list template that's not importing with one that is.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue before. I created a template using Task list and it was not appearing in add an app.

After some search on google I found that some of list templates hidden by design and task list was one of them.

The explanation for the template not being displayed can be one of the following ( except invalid templates of course, but then you would get a full-blown error ) :

1. the language of the template is different than the language of the site where you want the template to be used.
2. the version of the template does not match the minimum version difference accepted by the site where you are attempting to use it ( ex. you are saving a SharePoint 2007 list and are trying to use it in a SharePoint 2013 environment)
3. the template is hidden by design

Below are the list templates are hidden by design:

- Tasks(2010)
- Project Tasks
- Data Sources
- Converted Forms
- No Code Workflows
- Status List
- Workflow History
- No Code Public Workflows
- Persistent Storage List for MySite Published Feed
- Custom Workflow Process

For reference: [List saved as template does not appear under Add an app](http://blogs.technet.com/b/victorbutuza/archive/2014/09/08/list-saved-as-template-does-not-appear-under-add-an-app-or-what-lists-can-you-save-as-template-and-use-for-creating-other-lists-based-on-them.aspx)

Comment: Did you ever find a way to "unhide" them, though?

Comment: Hi vapcguy, sorry I don't remember now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I noticed that the featureId and the product version were missing in the list template gallery on the exported templates.

MS have a known issue...

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2779729/feature-id-not-assigned-when-saving-a-list-as-a-template

Basically switching on the ParserEnabled feature on your web site sorts the problem.

Need to re-create the templates again though once this is switched on.

This feature Seems to pump documents with metadata when they are loaded into SharePoint. Don't know if there are any side effects to switching it on.  Maybe I'll ask!

Comment: How can this be done on o365 sharepoint online?